# Use system variables in xml

Tags: xml, environment-variables, manifest

I have manifest file write in xml.

I want to use environment variable in it(Program Files), but it didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
<provider name="myapp"   
           resourceFileName="${env.ProgramFiles}\myfile.dll" 
           messageFileName="${env.ProgramFiles}\myfile.dll">
```

How can I use environment variable xml syntax?

Trying to run the manifest I get :

```
**** Warning: The resource file for publisher myapp was not found or could not be opened.
resourceFileName: ${env.ProgramFiles}\myfile.dll
```

Comment: This is not a problem with XML, it is a problem with the application you are using to process this XML. You haven't made it clear what this application is. (You speak of "manifest files", but many different applications use terms similar to this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what works for me:

```
<provider name="myapp"   
           resourceFileName="%ProgramFiles%\myfile.dll" 
           messageFileName="%ProgramFiles%\myfile.dll">
```